# How to use support FragmentManager in non-support space?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to implement a view with a tabhost, which derives from my `GeneralFragment` class:

```
using Android.App;
namespace mynamespace
  {
  public class GeneralFragment : Fragment
  { ... }
}
```

Now the child class of the upper parent class starts like this

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class OverviewFragment : GeneralFragment
    {
        FragmentTabHost _tabhost; // Should I do this?

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.F_Overview, container, false); 
            _tabhost = root.FindViewById<FragmentTabHost>(Resource.Id.tabhost);
            // Error line!
            // ChildFragmentManager makes problems.
            _tabhost.Setup(_parent,  ChildFragmentManager, 
                   Resource.Id.realtabcontent);
            _tabhost.AddTab(_tabhost.NewTabSpec("ATab").SetIndicator("ATab"),
                Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(CreateFragment)), null);
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot convert from 'Android.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your **GeneralFragment** as V4 version,instead of Fragment

```
using Android.App;
namespace mynamespace
  {
  public class GeneralFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
  { ... }
  }
```

**Fragment** != **Support.V4.App.Fragments** are not the same(they're **incompatible**).
You cannot combine them together.
Also,try to use ***SupportFragmentManager*** for V4 version(ChildFragmentManager available only for V4.Fragment).

Enjoy!